# How to get Float value from SCNText iOS?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scntext

I am not getting How to get float value from SCNText.If I print the SCNText.string I am able to see string in SCNText.Now I want like SCNText has float value flowed by characters, my requirement is extract float value from SCNText.I am getting how to extract Float value from SCNText.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Without being too meta, your render of `SCNText` is not the data. It's only a drawing on the screen.

The `float` value must have come from somewhere within your programs data or model.

Don't use the drawing on the screen as data. Use the original data.

Comment: Tq Warren Burton, But my requirement is, I need to modify exiting SCNText, need to perform mathematical calculation on SCNText. How can I achieve it? Please help me.